# Why was my edit rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Recently I made a edit suggestion: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/3542 that improved formatting, fixed confusing wording AND added the name of the term that the OP could not remember.

As far as I know, it seems like a good edit to me but it was rejected.

The reason provided is that it changed the original meaning too much. I don't see in what way I changed what the OP's original meaning.

Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 7):

I've taken a look at your edit, and the only reason I think your edit might be rejected is because someone wasn't familiar with some of the game term clarifications you used (i.e., "No-Lane rule" (where top lane is implicit) -> "No Top Lane rule" which instantiates the implication).

If you'd like to re-suggest it as an edit now, I will go ahead and approve it.

Comment: Is there a resuggest button or should I retype that again?

Comment: @Jay No need to retype it - just copy + paste. :)

Comment: Oh yea...duh! haha